# Can I add elements of two forms by using .serializeArray() function of Javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a Web Page which contains 3 forms. Each one has a large list of elements ( Input, select).
We were using query string to update the page on user submit using the serialize function and passing the params in the URL. In one such case, the length of the URL has crossed the maximum allowed string length in IE browser.

Now I am planning to change that to POST method and also send the elements using Jquery serializeArray function as the Server expected the data to be in form of an Array.

I am not able to find sufficient data on .serializeArray() function. 
Can the output of the .serializeArray() function for each form in my page be combined and then submitted ?
Is there any other method by which I can do this?.

Any suggestions is welcomed.

Comment: Yes they can be combined and submitted. Sufficient data on serializeArray()? Have you looked at the docs? http://api.jquery.com/serializeArray/

Answer (score 0):

You can combine the serialized data in an array and send

```
var data = new Array();

data[] = $("formone").serialize();
data[] = $("anotherform").serializa();

$.post("toapage.php", { formdatas : data }, function(msg) {
   alert(msg); //on success
});
```

Comment: Thanks. Your suggestion has moved me to the next step. I have changed the above code like this :                                                           `var data = new Array();
data.push( $('assessment_report_form').serialize());
data.push( $('refine_results').serialize());
alert(data);
$.post(URL, { CSV_DATA : data }, function(msg) {
return;
//alert(msg); //on success
}); `                                                                $.post is a Ajax Call. I don't need Ajax call. I there any other way from here to post the data.

Comment: @user1254174 You might decode the JSON to string on the hidden element and post as you would normally.

Comment: Covert the array to Json using [this library](https://github.com/douglascrockford/JSON-js)